# Требованя к хосту для установки сервера как в XAMPP

Tags: xampp, phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Всем добрый вечер.
Есть вот такой хелп на установку сервера на Windows в XAMPP
http://www.spikaapp.com/en/build/server/windows

Мне нужно установить такой же сервер только на реальный хост. Вот хочу узнать от вас требования к хосту и как это проделать?

Заранее большое всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Скачиваете [это](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Устанавливаете и изучаете [это](https://www.debian.org/CD/). Через полгода вопросы такие отпадут.